# css vertical column won't go 100% vertical

Tags: css

my web site is http://davewagnerart.com/index.html

I'd like the black column which has my thumbnails on the left to go all the way to the bottom of the site... can't seem to get it to do that. My CSS for the thumbs is:

```
#thumbnails  {
    position:absolute;
    top: 110px;
    width: 190px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set the height of the body and html elements as well.

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
```

telling a child element (#thumbnails) to be 100% height, it looks to its parents to see how big they are, and it will be 100% of them. However if the parent elements dont know how big they are, the child element can't do as its told.

You can learn about Viewports if you're interested

Comment: MANY thanks to everyone who chimed in. Y'all are awesome for helping a nube like me out. I tried all your suggestions and nothing seems to work! Any last ditch ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i've viewed that site in firefox and chrome and it extends to the bottom of the site already....

That being said you can also try replacing height: 100% with bottom: 0

Answer (score 0):

You set fixed height to `#painting_placement`, the same height has to be set to thumbnails. Of course together with `min-height`.

```
#thumbnails {
    height: 770px; /* height of #painting_placement + top indentation */
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries if tou want to get it working for different resolutions

eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    #thumbnails  {
    position:absolute;
    top: 180px;//increase the value of top
    width: 190px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    }
}
```

Like wise you could change the max-width and top according to each resolution which will make sure it will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#thumbnails  {
    position:absolute;
    top: 110px;
    width: 190px;
    height: auto;
padding-bottom:10px;    
    background-color: #000000;
}
```